# Upgrading to sound null safe, null is now not acceptable not sure how to fix this change as the rest of the code compiles

Tags: flutter, dart

```
E valueToEnum<E>(
  dynamic value,
  List<E> enumValues,
) =>
    enumValues.firstWhere(
      (E element) => describeEnum(element!) == '$value',
      orElse: () => null,
    );
```

I have added ?. to the E on top line with the value set to '' also but still no luck.

!. added on the null also throws error on the call to this function

Answer (score 0):

`orElse` depends on `enumValues` data type.

You can do

```dart
E? valueToEnum<E>(
  dynamic value,
  List<E?> enumValues,
) =>
    enumValues.firstWhere(
      (E? element) => ....,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
```

I think I have chosen try-catch instead of making it nullable list-datetype.

```dart
E? valueToEnum<E>(
  dynamic value,
  List<E> enumValues,
) {
  try {
    final foundValue = enumValues.firstWhere(
      (E? element) => describeEnum(element!) == '$value',
    );

    return foundValue;
  } catch (e) {}
}
```